# fold() into a set Koan is not accepted

Tags: kotlin

I am learning Kotlin via Koans here: https://play.kotlinlang.org/koans/Collections/Fold/Task.kt

this is my code so far:

```
// Return the set of products that were ordered by all customers
fun Shop.getProductsOrderedByAll(): Set<Product> {
    val orderedProductsByAll = this.customers.fold(mutableSetOf<Product>()) { 
        collector, c -> collector.plus(c.getOrderedProducts()).toMutableSet()
    }
    
    return orderedProductsByAll
}

fun Customer.getOrderedProducts(): List<Product> =
    this.orders.flatMap { o -> o.products }
```

Unfortunately the results is not accepted:

**Fail: testGetProductsOrderedByAllCustomers: The function 'getProductsOrderedByAll' is implemented incorrectly**

Any tips on what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have probably misunderstood the question...

> Return the set of products that were ordered by all customers

means

> Give me the products that are been purchased by all customer

therefore, you don't want to return "all the products that are been purchased at least 1 time by any customer", but only those that every customer have bought at least one time

At the end, "mathematically speaking" you don't want an "union", but an "intersection"... and the `collector` has infact an `intersect` method...

OT note:
also, consider that your `plus` method is not doing anything to the `set`, and your code is equivalent to:

```
return customers.flatMap { c -> c.getOrderedProducts() }.toSet()
```

Comment: Figured it out after your tips. Thanks Alberto!